# React Ref null on conditional render

Tags: reactjs, typescript

React ref animationRef is null whenever I conditionally render an element. It works fine outside of the condition. Is there any way to get the ref to have a value?

```
const When =
    (props: { children: React.ReactElement, condition: boolean })
        : React.ReactElement => props.condition ? props.children : <></>


export default class QLButton extends React.Component<{title: string}> {
    state: State;
    animationRef: React.RefObject<HTMLElement>
    constructor(props: {title: string}) {
        super(props);
        this.animationRef = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
            title: props.title,
            collapsed: true,
            animating: false
        }
    }

    render(): React.ReactElement {
        return <>
            <button onClick={this.onClick} className="ql-dropdown-btn">

                <When condition={this.state.animating}>
                    <div className="typing-text">
                        <span className="cursor" ref={this.animationRef} />
                    </div>
                </When>

            </button>
        </>
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React state updates are not synchronous.

When you call setState, you're requesting that React update the state. The actual state update happens later. This means that immediately after the `setState` call, the element

```
<span className="cursor" ref={this.animationRef} />
```

hasn't been created or rendered yet, so the ref points to null.

> In short, if the item is removed from DOM, ref will point to null.

Also, `ref` is set to the DOM node when it’s mounted, and set to null when the DOM node is removed. So everytime there is a re-render, it's set to `null` then `initialized` again.

See this example, when you click on the text, state is updated (re-render) then `ref` is set to null then back to the `element` -

```js
const {useState, useCallback} = React;

function App() {
  const ref = useCallback((e) => console.log("ref", e), []);
  const [iter, rerender] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div ref={ref} key={iter} onClick={() => rerender(iter + 1)}>
      click to remount
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(
      <App/>,
      document.getElementById("react")
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
 <div id="react">
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using componentDidUpdate instead of directly after a setState call, as setState is not synchronous as Aseem mentioned

```
   onClick() {
      this.setState(...);
      //componentDidUpdate is called
   }

   componentDidUpdate() {
      // do something
   }
```